# jquery toggle between login and registration in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two form login and registration, by default show login form. There has a link "Don't have account?" I want to create when click on link then registration form will show and login form will hide.

HTML Code:

```
 <div class="login_form">
         <div id="form">
        <h2>Login Here </h2>

        <form method="post" action="login.php" >
        <div class="form_elements">
        <label for="username">username</label>
        <input type="text" name="login_username" id="login_username" value="" />
        </div><!--end form_elements-->
        <div class="form_elements">
        <label for="username">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" value="" />
        </div><!--end form_elements-->
        <div class="form_elements">
            <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div><!--end form_elements--> 
        <br /> 
        <a href="#" id="show_register">Don't have a account?</a>
     </form>      
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_both"></div>
    <div class="register_form">
    <div id="form">
    <h2>Register Here </h2>
    <form method="post" action="login.php" name="">
    <div class="form_elements">
        <label for="username">username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="usename" value="" />
    </div><!--end form_elements-->

    <div class="form_elements">
        <label for="username">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
    </div><!--end form_elements-->

    <div class="form_elements">
        <label for="username">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" />
    </div><!--end form_elements-->

    <div class="form_elements">
        <label for="username">RePassword</label>
        <input type="password" name="repassword" id="repassword" value="" />
    </div><!--end form_elements-->

    <div class="form_elements">
            <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div><!--end form_elements-->
    </form>
    </div><!-- div form-->
```

jQuery Code:

```
    $(function(){
   ('#show_register').click(function(){
            $('.login_form').hide();
            $('.register_form').show();
            return false;
        });    
  });
```

Please guide me to solve this difficulty.

Comment: use dolor symbol $('#show_register')

Comment: You have two `div`s each with `id="form"` the id's should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as , `$` is missing in `show_register`

```
$(function(){
 $('#show_register').click(function(){
        $('.login_form').hide();
        $('.register_form').show();
        return false;
    });    
});
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.Thank you Amit.